# C to C++ : Converting structs to classes

Tags: c++, c, class, struct

So, this is probably a bit huge, and probably messy and incorrect (it's really beginner). I'm just learning C, and part of the work I'm required to do involves switching this program to a C++ program. The main thing I need to do is replace all structs with classes, and have all of the functions used in the code be class functions (members? If I recall...)

I have a pretty good grasp on a lot of basics, but the concept is to just sort of "modify" the code. I don't see how to "modify" my previous work by just switching to classes. As is, I feel like the program needs to pretty much be re-written to use classes. Maybe I'm missing the simplicity here. I don't want someone to do the work for me, I just want to know if there's a simple way to format my structs to work as classes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 

//Struct for friend array pointers.
typedef struct friendstruct{
        char *firstname;
        char *lastname;
        char *homephone;
        char *cellphone;
} frnd;
//Buffer for use in storing in the main program.
typedef struct bufferstruct{
        char firstname[20];
        char lastname[20];
        char homephone[20];
        char cellphone[20];
} frndbuff;
//Add friend function.
void addfriend(frnd friendarray[], frndbuff newfrnd, int count, int opened){
     friendarray[count].firstname = malloc(sizeof(newfrnd.firstname));  //Assign memory before copying string.
     friendarray[count].lastname = malloc(sizeof(newfrnd.lastname));
     friendarray[count].homephone = malloc(sizeof(newfrnd.homephone));
     friendarray[count].cellphone = malloc(sizeof(newfrnd.cellphone));
     strcpy(friendarray[count].firstname, newfrnd.firstname);
     //printf("%s", friendarray[count].firstname);
     //printf("%s", newfrnd.firstname);
     strcpy(friendarray[count].lastname, newfrnd.lastname);
     strcpy(friendarray[count].homephone, newfrnd.homephone);
     strcpy(friendarray[count].cellphone, newfrnd.cellphone);
     //friendarray[count].lastname = newfrnd.lastname;
     //friendarray[count].homephone = newfrnd.homephone;
     //friendarray[count].cellphone = newfrnd.cellphone;

     if(opened==0){
     printf("\nA new friend has been added to the phonebook.");
     }
}
//Deleteing friends.
int deletefriend(frnd friendarray[], frndbuff newfrnd, int count){
     int n = 0;
     int success = 0;
     while(n<count){
           if(strcmp(newfrnd.lastname,friendarray[n].lastname)==0){ //Comparing strings.
                 while(n<count-1){
                                 strcpy(friendarray[n].firstname, friendarray[n+1].firstname);
                                 strcpy(friendarray[n].lastname, friendarray[n+1].lastname);
                                 strcpy(friendarray[n].homephone, friendarray[n+1].homephone);//Removes previously used position.
                                 strcpy(friendarray[n].cellphone, friendarray[n+1].cellphone);
                                 //friendarray[n].lastname = friendarray[n+1].lastname;
                                 //friendarray[n].homephone = friendarray[n+1].homephone;
                                 //friendarray[n].cellphone = friendarray[n+1].cellphone;
                                 n++;
                 }
           success = 1;
           count = count - 1;
           break;
           }
           n++;
     }      
           if(success==1){
           printf("\nThe entry for %s has been removed from the phonebook.", newfrnd.lastname);
           }else{
           printf("\nThat entry was not found");
           }
           //printf("%i", count);
return count;
}
//Show friend by last namme. Identical to delete friend, without removal.
void showfriend(frnd friendarray[], frndbuff newfrnd, int count){
     int n = 0;
     int success = 0;
     while(n<count){
           if(strcmp(newfrnd.lastname, friendarray[n].lastname)==0){
           printf("\n\n%s %s %s (home) %s (cell)\n", friendarray[n].firstname, friendarray[n].lastname, friendarray[n].homephone, friendarray[n].cellphone);                      
           success = 1;
           break;
           }
     n++;
     }

           if(success==0){
           printf("\nThat entry was not found");
           }
}
//DIsplays entire phonebook.
void phonebook(frnd friendarray[], int count){
     int n = 0;
     //printf("%i", count); Used in debugging.
     while(n<count){
     printf("\n%s %s %s (home) %s (cell)\n", friendarray[n].firstname, friendarray[n].lastname, friendarray[n].homephone, friendarray[n].cellphone);
     n++;
     }
}
//Find friend based on last name.
void searchfriend(frnd friendarray[], frndbuff newfrnd, int count){
     int n = 0;
     int success = 0;
     while(n<count){
           if(strcmp(newfrnd.lastname, friendarray[n].lastname)==0){
           printf("\n\n%s %s %s (home) %s (cell)\n", friendarray[n].firstname, friendarray[n].lastname, friendarray[n].homephone, friendarray[n].cellphone); 
           success = 1;                     
           }
     n++;
     }

           if(success==0){
           printf("\nThat entry was not found");
           }
}                        

int main(){
    int option, option2;
    frndbuff currentfriend;
    frnd friendarray[50];
    int count = 0;
    int filecount = 0;
    int opened = 0;
    //Phonebook load previous to main loop.
    printf("\nDo you have a previously saved phonebook you'd like to load?\n1) Yes\n2) No\n");
    printf("\nChoose an option : ");
    scanf("%i", &option2);
        if(option2==1){

                  FILE *fileopen;
                  fileopen = fopen("phonebook.dat", "r"); //File open for reading.
                  if (fileopen != NULL){
                               filecount = 0;
                               opened = 1;
                               printf("\nYour previous phonebook has been loaded : ");
                               while(fscanf(fileopen, "%s %s %s (home) %s (work)\n",&currentfriend.firstname, &currentfriend.lastname, &currentfriend.homephone, &currentfriend.cellphone)==4){
                                                      printf("\n%s %s %s (home) %s (work)\n",currentfriend.firstname, currentfriend.lastname, currentfriend.homephone, currentfriend.cellphone);
                                                      addfriend(friendarray, currentfriend, filecount, opened);
                                                      filecount++;
                               }
                               count = filecount;
                  }else if(fileopen == NULL){
                               printf("\nA previous phonebook could not be found.");
                  }
    }

while(1==1){



    opened = 0;                
    printf("\n\nPhone Book Application\n1) Add Friend\n2) Delete Friend\n3) Show a Friend\n4) Show phone book\n5) Search by last name\n6) Quit\n");    
    printf("\n\nWhat option would you like to choose : ");
    scanf("%i", &option);  
    //Option ensuring.
    if(option<1 || option>6){
                printf("\nYou did not enter a valid option, please try again.");
                option = 6;
    }

    if(option==1){
                  printf("\nFirst Name : ");
                  scanf("%s", &currentfriend.firstname);
                  printf("\nLast Name : ");
                  scanf("%s", &currentfriend.lastname);
                  printf("\nHome Phone : ");
                  scanf("%s", &currentfriend.homephone);
                  printf("\nCell Phone : ");
                  scanf("%s", &currentfriend.cellphone);
                  //printf("%s", currentfriend.firstname); Debugging.
                  addfriend(friendarray, currentfriend, count, opened);


                  count++;
                  //printf("%i", count); Debugging.
                  //All options call the previously made functions and pass the buffer.
    }else if(option==2){
                  printf("\nEnter the last name of the friend you'd like to delete : ");
                  scanf("%s", &currentfriend.lastname);
                  count = deletefriend(friendarray, currentfriend, count);
    }else if(option==3){
                  printf("\nEnter the last name of the friend you'd like to view : ");
                  scanf("%s", &currentfriend.lastname);
                  showfriend(friendarray, currentfriend, count);
    }else if(option==4){
                  phonebook(friendarray, count);
    }else if(option==5){
                  printf("\nEnter the last name you'd like to search : ");
                  scanf("%s", &currentfriend.lastname);
                  searchfriend(friendarray, currentfriend, count);
    }else if(option==6){
                  option2 = 0;
                  printf("\nWould you like to save your phonebook to a file?\n1) Yes\n2) No");
                  printf("\n Choose an option : ");
                  scanf("%i", &option2);
                  if(option2==1){
                                 filecount = 0;
                                 FILE *filesave;
                                 filesave = fopen("phonebook.dat", "w"); //File open for writing.
                                 while(filecount<count){
                                 //File written in the same method it is read.
                                 fprintf(filesave, "%s %s %s (home) %s (work)\n",friendarray[filecount].firstname, friendarray[filecount].lastname, friendarray[filecount].homephone, friendarray[filecount].cellphone);
                                 filecount++;
                                 }
                  }
                  printf("\nThank you for using this Phone Book Application!");
                  break;
    }
}
//Files closed.
fclose(fileopen);
fclose(filesave);
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're just learning C, and you're already mixing it with C++?

Comment: Well, structs basically are classes, just with a default 'public' visibilty. All you need do really is change `typedef struct foostruct{...} foo; ` to  `class foo {public: ...}`

Comment: What are your requirements?  Are you just trying to move this to a .cpp from a .c?  Are you trying to rewrite it to be C++-idiomatic?  Object-oriented?  Just replace "struct" with "class"?

Comment: Yeah, if you want to convert this to proper C++, this code isn't salvagable.  You'll have to rewrite.  I wouldn't bother in this case.

Comment: It's actually in class. We're making a very sudden switch to C++. We didn't learn any of the C++ basics (which I luckily know some of), and we're expected to just take this and make it uses classes as opposed to structs. And yes, the main focus is switching the structs out for classes. I should add, one of the requirements if for the class variables to be private, and for the functions to now be members in the class.

Comment: Don't waste your time converting structures to classes unless you intend to move the related methods into the class as well.  Not a good Return On Investment (ROI), as the old code already works and has been tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference with C++ is to use **`std::string`** instead of the raw character arrays. Then you don't use `malloc` and `free`. You just let `std::string` take responsibility for the memory management.

Similarly, you'd use a **`std::vector`** for the storage of the friends.

You could also replace the i/o with C++ iostreams i/o, which is simpler and safer.

Bjarne Stroustrup wrote a little introductory article showing **[how to transform a little C program into C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/new_learning.pdf)** ("Learning Standard C++ as a New Language", C/C++ Users Journal pp 43-54 May 1999).

You will just have to "unlearn" some C ways of doing things, and adopt more C++'ish ways. :-)

Comment: Thanks for this. I assumed something needed to be changed with the strings to make this pretty.

Comment: Is the iostreams i/o actually simpler than C's I/O?  Personally, I find that the formatting of I/O in C is simpler than C++.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: i would tend to agree with you re formatting. and much else. but for *simple* i/o iostreams simplify things, in particular inputting arbitrary long lines of text (via std::getline). and it's safer. there are fewer ways to invoke Undefined Behavior. :-)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, in C++, there's very little difference between structs and classes.

A class is a struct where fields/methods are private by default.

```
struct Foo {
    //Content here
};
```

is the same as

```
class Foo {
public:
    //Content here
};
```

But, of course, that's not using all the "good stuff" of C++ classes.

1. Replace `typedef struct X { ... } Y;` by just `struct X { ... }` or `struct Y { ... };`. There's not much point in using typedefs like that in C++.
2. If you don't mean "converting your code to classes" but rather "using the standard C++ classes instead of C features", then replace `char name[N]` by `std::string name;`, replace `Type[]` by `std::vector<Type>` (don't forget to pass the vector to functions by reference, if you don't know what passing by reference is - learn it, it's an important concept).
3. If you use C++ standard strings, then `malloc`/`free`/`strcpy` are no longer needed. Instead of `strcpy(a, b);` just use `a = b;`

If you follow these tips right, I believe your code will be massively simplified. Then, you'll find that some of your functions simply become unnecessary. For instance, `addfriend` will probably be replaced by `vector.push_back`.

Comment: I kind of agree. I think I'll just start from basics, and transcribe it from C to C++ using the normal C++ standards, and applying the stuff people helped me with. Thanks!

Comment: You have to remember that the OP is asking how to convert C structs to C++ classes, not C++ structs to C++ classes.

Answer (score 0):

- The switch to `std::string` and `std::vector<>` is well recommended in existing answers.

  - `std::string` has value semantics, which means you can simply use `==` to compare strings, and `=` to assign into a string.
- You won't need a friend-buff class or struct... just use the friend class everywhere.
- You may want to add a constructor to it so you can create an instance using simply `Friend(firstname, lastname, homephone, cellphone)`, without needing to explicitly assign to each of those members every time (hint - use an "initialisation list").

  - Because `std::string` has value semantics (as distinct from being pointer-like), you won't need to create a copy constructor or destructor to duplicate or clean up the memory used by the strings... it will all just work.
- You can use Standard algorithms to do things like erase an element from a `vector`... all easily googled or found on stackoverflow.
- iostreams means you can write code to output variables without specifying the variable's type (as you must with printf()) - the compiler automatically finds appropriate code.  You'll need to `#include <iostream>` then `std::cout << variable << "string literals\n";` etc..

  - You won't need to use `std::endl` or `std::flush` unless you want output to appear immediately even though you're not waiting for input - simply `\n` is usually the right choice although many C++ books/tutorials etc. show `endl`.